# Applying sgolay for calculation velocity/acceleration with nonuniform Fs

Tags: matlab, filter

I have some x and y (pixel) coordinates that were collected using a sensor that as not a steady Fs (sample rate) and want to apply a SGOLAY filter to my signal and compute the velocity and acceleration of the movement.

I'm following the example in the [Mathworks help secction](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolay.html) regarding Savitzky-Golay Differentiation. But they use a predetermined fixed Fs can someone help me and explain how can I apply the filter for an variable Fs (I have the time stamp for each coordinate).

Answer (score 0):

The filter does not depend on the sample rate but is applied to a fixed number of points (i.e. the input `framelen`). Nevertheless, you are right that the signal should ideally be equally spaced.

1. apply the filter as it is to a variable-spaced signal (in terms of time)
2. make the signal equally spaced (i.e. interpolate it... as we don't know the signals, I cannot recommend any interpolation method for this)
3. make the filter time variable

For the last, I would recommend to use different frame-length and build your time-variable filtered signal afterwards. Here is a quick example of what I thought of

```
% create random signal
x = ([1:50,51:2:150].')/10; % "time" vector
sig = rand(100,1)+sin(x); % signal vector

% different factors => will be frame length
fct = round( 1./diff(x) );
fct_uq = unique(fct);

% allocate memory
Y = NaN(length(sig),length(fct_uq));
sig_flt = NaN(size(sig));
% loop over unique "factors"
for i = 1:length(fct_uq)
    % ensure odd framelen
    framelen = 2*floor(fct_uq(i)/2)+1;
    % apply filter
    y = sgolayfilt(sig,3,framelen);
    % store results
    Y(:,i) = y;

    % build new filtered signal
    lg = fct == fct_uq(i);
    sig_flt(lg) = y(lg);
end
% plot
plot(x,[sig,sig_flt], x,Y,'--')
```